# Advanced Search Like with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Content objects (which i defined below)

```
List<Content> ContentList;
```

I am am trying to create a method to search this list using LINQ. The method gets this list as a parameter but it also gets a Query object which is defined like so

```
public class DomainQuery
{
  public List<string> PhrasesIncludeAny { get; set; }
  public List<string> PhrasesIncludeAll { get; set; }
  public List<string> PhrasesExcludeAll { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreatedAfter { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreatedBefore { get; set; }
}
```

The content object is defined as

```
public class Content
{
  public List<string> Summary{ get; set; }
  public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

The linq statement needs to go through each one of the Content object and pick only those that match the query. The search of phrases is on the Summary field. For instance, the summary must include all the phrases in the PhrasesIncludeAll list (blue,red greed), any of the phrases: sky, land, car (PhrasesIncludeAny) but exclude: Canada, US, UK.

Comment: That is cool plan... Would you mind to add question to your post in addition to list of requirement to clarify what piece of code do you have problem with during implementations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming i understood what you want your operators to do it should look something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var queryInfo = new DomainQuery();
    var ContentList = new List<Content>();

    var query = ContentList
        .Where(q=>queryInfo.PhrasesIncludeAny
            .Any(item=>q.Summary.Any(subitem=>subitem == item)))
        .Where(q=>queryInfo.PhrasesIncludeAll
            .All(item=>q.Summary.All(subitem=>subitem == item)))
        .Where(q=>!queryInfo.PhrasesIncludeAll
            .All(item=>q.Summary.All(subitem=>subitem == item)))
        .Where(q=>q.CreatedDate < queryInfo.CreatedBefore)
        .Where(q=>q.CreatedDate > queryInfo.CreatedAfter);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also try this

```
List<Content> ContentList = new List<Content>() 
                        { new Content { CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, Summary = new List<string>() { "America", "Pakistan", "India", "England" } }, 
                          new  Content { CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, Summary = new List<string>() { "Germany", "Holland", "Aus", "NewZealand" } }};

DomainQuery domainQuery = new DomainQuery { CreatedAfter = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4), PhrasesExcludeAll = new List<string>() { "Aus" }, CreatedBefore = DateTime.Now, PhrasesIncludeAll = new List<string>() { "America", "Pakistan", "India", "England" }, PhrasesIncludeAny = new List<string>() { "India" } };

var result = ContentList.Where(c => domainQuery.PhrasesIncludeAny
                        .Any(item => c.Summary.Any(subItem => subItem == item))
           && !domainQuery.PhrasesExcludeAll.Any(item => c.Summary.Any(subItem => subItem == item))
           && !c.Summary.Except(domainQuery.PhrasesIncludeAll).Any()
           && c.CreatedDate < domainQuery.CreatedBefore
           && c.CreatedDate > domainQuery.CreatedAfter);



        foreach (var res in result)
        {
            res.Summary.ForEach(r => {
                    Console.WriteLine(r);
                });

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```